# How to make VSCode always run main.py

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am writing my first library in Python, When developing I want my run code button in VS Code to always start running the code from the main.py file in the root directory. I have added a new configuration to launch.json however I seem to be unable to use this configuration as default. How can I do this/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right solution is to just change "program" in launch.json to:

```
"program": "main.py",
```

If trying to add the {workspaceFolder} it gives a FileNotFoundError.

Comment: @Dante I agree, Answer accepted

Answer (score 9):

You need to put the '`launch.json`' under the '`.vscode`' folder inside your workspace. Then `Run` > `Run Without Debugging` (shortcut on windows `CTRL+F5`)

[image]

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the `launch.json` with the below settings for key `program`. You may want to point `program` to the file which you want to execute. In the below case `main.py` is present in my workspace folder only. You can modify it as per your requirement.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I managed to get this. Now how can I tell VSCode to use this config by default?

Comment: Just execute the code using Debug > Start Without Debugging (Shortcut on Mac is ^ F5)