# How do I make Visual Studio Code always run the main python file when the Run button is clicked?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Before I say anything, I want to make it clear that I am not talking about the debug menu, I am talking about this button:
[image]

When I press that run button in a different python file, in the same workspace, it'll try to run that file which I don't want. I want it to always run the main python file. (`main.py` for me)

I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395036/how-to-make-vscode-always-run-main-py), but adding a `launch.json` to the `.vscode` folder didn't help.

So how do I make that Run button always execute `main.py`?

Comment: Did you try "Run > Run Without Debugging" section.

Comment: I have found this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/ho5cc2/how_to_make_run_button_to_run_python_code_in/). Dont know how much of a use it could be but I don't think there really is a way. Personally I prefer to run my code through `CMD Pallets` as it allows me to select specific files for testing and if you're writing `TDD` or `BDD` code you'll need to run the code manually anyways.

Comment: @uozcan12, yes but there is no way I'm going to get used to pressing that.

Answer (score -1):

As is said in the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395036/how-to-make-vscode-always-run-main-py) you mentioned.

Add this code to your `launch.json` : `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

At the same time, you should know that **launch.json** is effective for debug mode, so please switch the running mode and use shortcuts **F5** or **Debug Python File**.

Comment: I have and, yes, I do know both these things, but I don't want to go in debug mode.

Comment: If you must use Run Python File, you can submit a request for this function to the developer in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python), although they will still tell you to use the debug mode.